# Double dollar variables with arrays

Tags: php, syntax

I am trying to access the first item of an array using the double dollar syntax, but it doesn't work as I would want it to.

```
<?php

$a = 'test';
$test = ['a', 'b'];
echo $$a[0];
```

This will say that the variable t is undefined, because it renders the $a[0] first (which is a "t") and then tries to access the variable called $t as a result.

What I want is something along the line of these (none of the following snippets work, they are just things I tried, to illustrate the idea)

```
<?php

$a = 'test';
$test = ['a', 'b'];
echo {$$a}[0];
```

Or

```
<?php

$a = 'test';
$test = ['a', 'b'];
echo ${$$a}[0];
```

Basically, tell PHP that the $$a part gets priority.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You were very close. You need to tell PHP to evaluate the `$a` alone. Try:

```
<?php

$a = 'test';
$test = ['a', 'b'];
echo ${$a}[0];
```

[Example](https://ideone.com/er2cUB)