# Get value of variable by name in case it is array item, possibly from superglobal

Tags: php, variables, superglobals

Is this at all possible to get a value from variable accessed by name in case it refers to an indexed array item? Actually I planned to do this trick with $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] but I found out that $$ doesn't get well with any specific array item.

```
$a = '555';
$b = 'a';
var_dump($$b);

$a = array (1,2,3);
$b = 'a';
var_dump($$b);
$b = 'a[1]';
var_dump($$b);
```

First two vardumps work as expected, but the last one gives **Notice: Undefined variable: a[1]** even though it obviously exists. And I want it to return 2.

upd: PHP 7.1.16

Comment: Which PHP version are you using? For me it returns `y` (using 7.2.10)

Comment: you can do var_dump($$b[1]); but I'm not sure if that's what you want

Comment: A variable named `a[1]` does *not* exist, only `a` does.

Comment: @Peter true and valid point^^ though I suppose OP is expecting similar results to `var_dump($a[1])` (which would return `2`) ...

Comment: Regarding your actual use case, are you saying you have the string `_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` in a variable? If so, how did that happen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Double dollar variables with arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30454138/double-dollar-variables-with-arrays)

Comment: @iainn that happen because I'm working on a template engine and I want it to be able to resolve macroses containing array items with indices, including superglobals.

Comment: @treyBake yes, I want some way to resolve strings like `d['e']` into actual values of `$d['e']` provided I'm not the one who writes these strings. But I can set the syntax to whatever I like.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with php you will need to parse the string and figure out how to get the value from variable. If you have only limited number of things like one variable and number in brackets it should not be that hard to parse and process. More accurate error message should be invlid character in variable literal (`[]` should be be possible to be in reference variable the same as it's not possible in normal variable name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is simple parser for just arrays of strings or numbers

```
function parse($str) {
    // regex explanation:
    // ^ - beging of the string
    // valid name inside capture group with at least one character
    // \[ literal open bracket
    // ([^\]]+) - capture group with non closing bracket
    // \] - closing bracket
    // $ - end of string
    $re = "/^([a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*)\[([^\]]+)\]$/";
    if (preg_match($re, $str, $match)) {
        $var = $match[1];
        global $$var;
        // regex for any integer
        if (preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/", $match[2])) {
            // convert integera like string to integer
            return $$var[intval($match[2])];
        } else {
            // remove quotes from beginning and ending of a string
            return $$var[trim($match[2], "\"'")];
        }
    } else {
        return $$str;
    }
}

$a = array (1,2,3);
$b = 'a';
var_dump($$b);
$b = 'a[1]';
var_dump(parse($b));

$a = array("foo" => "hello");
$b = 'a["foo"]';
var_dump(parse($b));
echo parse("_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']");
```

regex for variable name can be found in [php docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)

the only limitation is that variable need to be global, but _SERVER is always global so it shouldn't matter.